# Peculiarities of MySQL's IN clause

Tags: mysql, optimization

I've just solved an interesting problem using MySQL's IN, but I don't know what this "trick" is called.

In my design I needed to filter out rows that either did not require a certain skill, or for which the skill name and the skill level were met. Here's the solution:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
    skillname = "" OR
    (skillname, skilllevel) IN (
        SELECT name, level FROM skills WHERE user="Mikhail"
    )
```

I didn't know that **`expr` IN (`value`,...)**, as according to [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) both `expr` and `value` can be multiple columns.

What is this called, and are there more shortcuts like these?
More importantly - is there a way to convert this query to match `skilllevel` as "greater than or equal to"?

---

**Solution** as per @yokoloko (though he won't admit it)

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE
    skillname = "" OR
    skillname IN (
        SELECT name FROM skills WHERE user="Mikhail" AND level >= t1.skilllevel
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know how is it called but if I understand well you can do something like this to get the greater than :

```
SELECT * FROM table t1 WHERE
    skillname = "" OR
    (skillname, skilllevel) IN (
        SELECT name, level FROM skills s WHERE user="Mikhail" and t1.skilllevel >= s.level
    )
```

But I don't know if it's really well optimized.

Comment: makes sense, though since IN compares equality, still wouldn't work

Comment: I believe if you just remove the `skilllevel` from the left of `IN` and `level` from SELECT -- the entire query will work since `name` won't be returned if the level isn't matched

Comment: Yes but you won't know the skilllevel then, and apparently you need it.

Comment: The subquery WHERE clause can still access t1.skilllevel so the `>=` will work correctly

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, the `IN` predicate always compares values for *equality*, not greater than or equal to.

Here's how I'd write it:

```
SELECT table.* 
FROM table WHERE skillname = ''
UNION ALL
SELECT table.* 
FROM table JOIN skills 
  ON table.skillname = skills.name AND table.skilllevel >= skills.level
WHERE skills.user = 'Mikhail'
```

As for terminology of your query, @guide points out that you ran a *row subquery*, and compared it to a literal row using *row constructor* syntax.  SQL allows you to create anonymous rows using columns, expressions, or values, and use them in certain circumstances, like comparing to another row with a compatible number of columns.  I'd call this *row comparison*.

You can also use this in a join condition, but if you want equality comparison for one column and inequality for another column, it gets really unclear:

```
SELECT table.* 
FROM table JOIN skills 
  ON (table.skillname, table.skilllevel) >= (skills.name, skills.level)
WHERE skills.user = 'Mikhail'
```

The above would probably not do what you want.  Example:

```
SELECT (1,2) = (1,2);   -- returns true (i.e. 1 in MySQL)

SELECT (1,2) >= (1,2);  -- returns true

SELECT (1,3) >= (1,2);  -- returns true

SELECT (1,2) >= (1,3);  -- returns false

SELECT (2,3) >= (1,2);  -- returns true

SELECT (1,3) >= (2,2);  -- returns false
```

The same comparison operator is applied to all columns in these rows.  But it also short-circuits (unlike `AND`):

```
SELECT (2,3) >= (1,4);  -- returns true
```

The 2 is greater than 1, but 3 is not greater than 4.  Confusing?  Consider an example of alphabetizing:

```
SELECT ('Smith', 'Agent') >= ('Anderson', 'Thomas'); -- returns true
```

Smith is greater than Anderson, but Agent is not greater than Thomas.  Nevertheless, we know how we would order these two names in a phone book.

The point of all this is that you need to write complete boolean expressions if you want more control over the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

That's called [row subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/row-subqueries.html)

> A row subquery is a subquery variant that returns a single row and can
>   thus return more than one column value.

Comment: row subquery and not raw of course. (cannot edit less than 6 caracters)